# Compute the probability density of a function of a random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification

First I made this question for myself just out of curiosity. But got stuck in the middle of solving it.

**The question:**
Say we have a probability density function of a continuous stochastic variable X as

$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
    \frac{2}{\pi^2}x & 0\leq x\leq\pi \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$

If we make another continuous stochastic variable Y by

$$Y=\sin X \space(i.e. \space y=\sin x)$$

what is the probability density function of Y gonna be?
$$\\$$

**My solution:**
$$\int_0^1 f_Y(y) dy = 1 , \int_0^\pi f_X(x)dx=1\\ 
\rightarrow \int_0^1 f_Y(y) dy\space =\int_0^\pi f_X(x)dx\space \\=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}f_X(x)dx+\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\pi f_X(x)dx\\=\int_0^1\frac{2}{\pi^2}x\space \frac{dx}{dy}\space dy+\int_1^0 \frac{2}{\pi^2}x\frac{dx}{dy}\space dy$$

Now, for $x\in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}],\space x$ can be written as $arcsin(y)$ and the $x$ and $\frac{dx}{dy}$ in the integral on the left side can be substituted with functions of $y$. So now we have
$$\int_0^1\frac{2}{\pi^2}x\space \frac{dx}{dy}\space dy =\int_0^1\frac{2}{\pi^2}\arcsin(y)\cdot\frac{d}{dy}\arcsin(y)\cdot dy=\int_0^1\frac{2}{\pi^2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy$$

And now I have a problem. What about the second integral? For that domain$([\frac{\pi}{2},\pi])$, the inverse function of $x$ doesn't exist and at this point I don't know how to convert the second integral above to the function $y$ (the first integral was able). Could someone teach me how to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You cannot find $f_Y$ by just computing its integral from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: I thought if I could convert the functions of $x$ in those integrals to functions of y, I would have found the $f_Y(y)$. Because $$\int_0^1 f_Y(y)dy=\int_0^1 (some\space function\space of\space y)dy \rightarrow F_Y(y)=(the function\space of\space y)$$

Comment: See https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/functions-of-random-variables-and-their-distribution

Comment: It is better to avoid "getting stuck" in the title. The title should have a mathematical content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that $Y=g(X)$. Formally speaking (here $g$ has to be strictly increasing) the CDF of $Y$ is defined by $F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(g(X)\leq y)=P(X\leq g^{-1}(y))=F_X(g^{-1}(y))$, hence the density of $Y$ is its derivative:
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(y))}f_X(g^{-1}(y)).
$$
In your case, as $\sin$ is not strictly increasing on $[0,\pi]$ you have
$$
\begin{align*}
P(\sin X\leq y)&=P(X\leq \arcsin y)+P(X\geq \pi-\arcsin y ),\\
&=F_X(\arcsin y)+1-F_X(\pi-\arcsin y).
\end{align*}
$$
All computations done, you end up with
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1[}(y).
$$

Comment: I strongly encourage you to do the computations yourself!